# Issues while submitting iOS app on Facebook for approval

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to upload my iPad application, .ipa for Facebook approval. 
I have prepared the simulator build, compressed it in .zip format and provided the APP URL link.

Also I have submitted the screen-shots and notes. I have requested for user_likes, publish_action and manage_pages.

However, when I try to save, it get following warnings. [image]

```
Your app must have a logo

Your app must have long description set 

Your app must have a Privacy Policy URL
```

**I am confused, where to set these values? Can these values be part of the .ipa ? If yes, then please confirm. Especially the privacy policy URL**

Did some one faced this issue? Please guide.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [app store approval processes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2):

I searched and saw that there is additional tab "App Details". We need to fill the info in that tab.

[image]

Thanks